# Spray's integration with idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, spray

I have a simple spray service actor

```
class SimplService(service: AService) extends HttpServiceActor
  with MyJsonProtocol
  with SprayJsonSupport {

  override def receive: Receive = runRoute {
    path("a") {
      get {
        parameter('param.as[String]) { p =>
          complete {
            service.foo(p)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

AService's foo methods returns `Future[List[SomeClass]]`
There is an implcict a jsonFormat declared in `MyJsonProtocol`(which of course extends from DefaultJsonProtocol) for `SomeClass`

When running in intellij idea i get such compile time error

```
could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller[scala.concurrent.Future[List[SomeClass]]]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The problem was in absence of implicit Execution context.
IMHO, error message might be better